# How to run only one TestNG class from Maven Surefire Plugin in single thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, testng, allure

I'm use allure framevork + testNG for reporting test. And I want to run **only one test class** in parallel from maven.

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                </argLine>

                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>

                <!--suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles-->
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

1. If I use the `<suiteXmlFiles>`, then the aspectj will not see my tests, and than I need write all tests classes in xml (I don't wan't to do it, cause I'm use aspectj)
2. If I set `<parallel>` in maven-surefire-plagin - than all methods in all classes was parallel.

Maybe I can include one class to parallel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mvn test -Dtest=classname` with your current pom declaration as above.

This would trigger testmethods in the above class in parallel.